# Can HBase Access Text Documents and CSV Documents Just as Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase

In Hadoop, I can easily create Map/Reduce apps which access and process data in huge text files and csv files.  My question is  can Hbase do the same and access such huge files, or HBase has other uses?

Hbase runs queries just as relational databases; so, I kind of have a hard time to understand the advantage of HBase, unless it  can access huge text and csv files just as Hadoop does.

Comment: Read Google's BigTable whitepaper and Amazon's Dynamo whitepaper.  They do a good job of explaining what distributed database (such as HBase) are and what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Hbase is just a store. And a store never accesses anything. Rather you access the store to fetch or put the data. Like any other datastore Hbase has only one job to do, store your data and make it available to you whenever you need it. You can write MapReduce jobs or sequential Java programs etc etc to put data into Hbase or fetch data from it. It's totally upto you which path you prefer.

Coming to the second part of your question, Hbase never ever works like traditional relational databases. Everything, starting from storing the data to accessing the data, is totally different. The advantage of using Hbase is that you can store really really huge amount of data into it and have random read/write access. The data can be of any type viz. text, csv, tsv, binary etc etc. But, before going ahead, you must think well whether Hbase is a suitable choice for you or not, as one size doesn't fit all.

HTH

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from your reply, I conclude the following: a)Putting a huge text file as a field in an Hbase table is in most cases not useful.  b)The real advantage of HBase is the following: In relational databases querying a huge table in some cases could take hours; but in HBase,even though the table might be huge, but you will not have queries which would take hours.

Comment: each Hbase cell has a threshold as far as size of the data is concerned which defaults to 100MB. Although you can alter this, but it may degrade the performance, as each Hbase cell is not just the data it holds. it contains some other params like timestamp etc. time taken by a query basically depends on three things :1- how efficient is your cluster deployment.2- how advanced is your storage structure.3- how good is the code or script you have written to fetch the data. it's the distributed nature of Hbase which makes the fetching rapid.